# Push elements dynamically to a multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

How can I create and push elements to a multidimensional array? 
I want to achieve an array like this:

```
var sourceData = [
                [0, 99.75], [1, 99.77],
                [2, 99.78], [3, 99.84],
                [4, 99.82], [5, 99.82],
                [6, 99.76], [7, 99.78],
                [8, 99.8], [9, 99.65],
                [10, 99.94], [11, 99.8]
            ];
```

Now, I want the first value in each sub-array to increment like above, 0,1,2, etc. The values on the right of the sub-array should be retrieved from a json object eg :

```
{
    "closingbal": "39.00",
    "customer_id": "33",
    "monthlycashInfow": 658,
    "monthlycashOutfow": 674,
    "monthyear": "2017-01",
    "netcashflow": -16,
    "openingbal": "3.00",
    "ratioinfoutflow": 0.4286,
    "ratioinfoutflowamount": 0.9763,
    "transnoInflow": 3,
    "transnoOutflow": 7
},
{
    "closingbal": "130.00",
    "customer_id": "33",
    "monthlycashInfow": 4970,
    "monthlycashOutfow": 4949,
    "monthyear": "2016-12",
    "netcashflow": 21,
    "openingbal": "19.00",
    "ratioinfoutflow": 0.4444,
    "ratioinfoutflowamount": 1.0042,
    "transnoInflow": 12,
    "transnoOutflow": 27
},
{
    "closingbal": "1064.00",
    "customer_id": "33",
    "monthlycashInfow": 3030,
    "monthlycashOutfow": 4113,
    "monthyear": "2016-11",
    "netcashflow": -1083,
    "openingbal": "0.00",
    "ratioinfoutflow": 0.24,
    "ratioinfoutflowamount": 0.7367,
    "transnoInflow": 6,
    "transnoOutflow": 25
}
```

I need the values fro "netcashflow" to be populated on the right.

How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

This is what I have tried:

```
var values = [];
            $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                if (key == 'cashflows') {
                    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                        if(!values[i])
                            values[i] = [];
                        for(var j = 0; j < json.cashflows.cashflow.length; j++) {
                            var row = json.cashflows.cashflow[j];
                            values.push(i+", " +row['netcashflow']);
                            //values[i].push();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: @whodini9 Let me update the question with what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array in the request format. The 2nd parameter passed to Array#map is the current index, which can use as the incremented value:

```js
var data = [{"closingbal":"39.00","customer_id":"33","monthlycashInfow":658,"monthlycashOutfow":674,"monthyear":"2017-01","netcashflow":-16,"openingbal":"3.00","ratioinfoutflow":0.4286,"ratioinfoutflowamount":0.9763,"transnoInflow":3,"transnoOutflow":7},{"closingbal":"130.00","customer_id":"33","monthlycashInfow":4970,"monthlycashOutfow":4949,"monthyear":"2016-12","netcashflow":21,"openingbal":"19.00","ratioinfoutflow":0.4444,"ratioinfoutflowamount":1.0042,"transnoInflow":12,"transnoOutflow":27},{"closingbal":"1064.00","customer_id":"33","monthlycashInfow":3030,"monthlycashOutfow":4113,"monthyear":"2016-11","netcashflow":-1083,"openingbal":"0.00","ratioinfoutflow":0.24,"ratioinfoutflowamount":0.7367,"transnoInflow":6,"transnoOutflow":25}];

var sourceData = data.map(function(o, i) {
  return [i, o.netcashflow];
});

console.log(sourceData);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, the mappings are okay but it doesn't generate an array. I'm getting this: 0,-16,1,21,2,-1083,3,1000,4,-206,5,-1305,6,2415,7,132,8,351,9,454,10,-203,11,206,12,-933

Comment: @Mathenge - run the snippet, and look at your browser's console. It generates an array. There is another problem in your code.

Comment: I'm looking into it, just one more question please, should "var data" be an array? @Ori Drori

Comment: @Mathenge: You're probably using `alert()` to view the result. Use proper logging and debugging tools.

Comment: @Mathenge - according to the format of the data it looks like an array, but you'll have to look at the original data.

Comment: @OriDrori I got it to work, the problem was the data i was passing. Your method made it happen. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ori Dori's method, I was able to achieve it like this:

```
var data;
            var objectStringArray;
            $.each(json, function (key, value) {
                if (key == 'cashflows') {
                    data = JSON.stringify(json.cashflows.cashflow);
                    objectStringArray = (new Function("return " + data+ ";")());
                }
            });
            var sourceData = objectStringArray.map(function(o, i) {
                return [i, o.netcashflow];
            });
```